# Remove then add punctuation at same indices using replace

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to convert a sentence with Chinese characters to Pinyin.

`Aka: 你好, 吗? => ni hao, ma?`

I want to initially strip out sentence punctuation so I don't need to waste loops checking for equality against a dictionary, but would ultimately like to preserve the locations of punctuation and add them back to the translation.

I get the conversion from Chinese to Pinyin, and am able to add back in the `?` at the end, but am not sure how to replace the comma in the new sentence.

```
/*
  Remove spaces periods, commas, and question marks
*/
function removePunctuation (str) {
  return str.replace(/[.,\? ]/g, '');
}

function convertToPinyin () {
  var cn = chinese_sentence; //你好, 吗?
  var cn2 = removePunctuation(cn); //你好吗
  var cn3 = cn2.split(''); //['你', '好', '吗']
  var pinyin = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cn3.length; i++) {
    if (cn3[i] in dictionary_json) {
      pinyin.push(dictionary_json[cn3[i]].pinyin);
    }
  }
  // cn = 你好, 吗?
  // replace '你好吗' with 'ni hao ma'
  // get 'ni hao, ma?'

  return cn.replace(cn2, pinyin.join(' '));
}

var pinyin = convertToPinyin();

console.log('pinyin', pinyin); //ni hao ma?
//should get 'ni hao, ma?'
```

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on. Looks like your replacing letter by letter via split. Is that right? If you remove all the punctuation first, it gets lost.

Comment: Yes. I'm replacing each character (你好吗) against its pinyin match (ni hao ma) in a dictionary. Then want to add back in the punctuation

Comment: If its a character by character sequence replacement, you'd be better off with a single find and replace regex, matching the non-punctuation `[^.,\? ]+` then in a callback, replace either the translation or the matched character.

Comment: But, this `[^.,\? ]+` would do the same as split, except your matching the word. Or, it can be a single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than removing the punctuation, you can instead simply remove the white space and simply have them as normal characters, and then during you dictionary check look if the character being looked at is not a punctuation character first:

```
function convertToPinyin () {
  var cn = '你好, 吗?'; //你好, 吗?
  var cn2 = cn.replace(/\s/g, ''); //你好,吗?  
  var cn3 = cn2.split(''); //['你', ',', '好', '吗', '?']
  var pinyin = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cn3.length; i++) {
    if(!/[.,\? ]/.test(cn3[i])) // If not punctuation 
    { 
        if (cn3[i] in dictionary_json) // Then convert
            pinyin.push(dictionary_json[cn3[i]].pinyin);
    } else {
        pinyin.push(cn3[i]);
    }
  } 
  return cn.replace(cn2, pinyin.join(' '));
}
```

This way you will save where the punctuation is and convert the items at the same time, it will also not check the dictionary if it's not a Chinese character.

Comment: Spencer, good idea, but it doesn't work. `console.log(cn2, pinyin.join(' '));` outputs `你好,吗? ni hao ma`, and doing a replace on these doesn't work. `return cn.replace(cn2, pinyin.join(' '));` gives `你好, 吗?` as output. Output should be `ni hao, ma?`

Comment: This is because the `pinyin.push(...` is filtering out the punctuation `if(!/[.,\? ]/.test(cn3[i]))`, so doing the replace will not include them

Comment: I guess this could easily be solved with just `array.splice` to add the punctuation back to the original spot

Comment: @Growler Ah I think see now, you just need to add an `else` and `push` the non-converted character.

Comment: It wont replace either because we removed the spaces at the beginning.  See here: `console.log(cn2); //你好,吗?`... `console.log(cn); // 你好, 吗?` Since we already solved retaining the punctuation, we can simply now return `return pinyin.join(' ');` = `ni hao , ma?`

Comment: @Growler Then would it work if I didn't remove the spaces?